# Azure Data Factory - Scale elasticpool with web activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-elasticpool

I'm trying to scale my Azure elasticpool in datafactory with a web activity task passing the following api call:

```
{
    "url": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subID/resourceGroups/RGNAME/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqlservername/elasticPools/elasticpoolname?api-version=2020-08-01-preview",
    "method": "PUT",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": {
        "sku": {
            "name": "StandardPool",
            "tier": "Standard",
            "capacity": "50"
        },
        "location": "West Europe"
    },
    "authentication": {
        "type": "MSI",
        "resource": "https://management.azure.com/"
    }
}
```

The activity fails, but the strange thing is that the scale actually works. Even though the scaling works I obviously don't want the activity to fail.

ADF has a contributor role in SQLServer

Any idea?

Here is the error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
    "message": "The client 'ADF ID' with object id 'ADF ID' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/locations/elasticPoolOperationResults/read' over scope '/subscriptions/SUBID/resourceGroups/RGNAME/providers/Microsoft.Sql/locations/westeurope/elasticPoolOperationResults/id' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I reproduce same my environment. I got same error.

[image]

To resolve this issue. Go to SQL server -> Access control (IAM) + Add Contributor role -> Go to members Assign access to Manage identity and select azure data factory.

[image]

> **Try with below body and header:**

**Header:** `Content-Type application/json`

**Body:** {"sku":{"name":"GP_Gen5_2","tier":"GeneralPurpose"},"location":"eastus"}

**Resource:** https://management.azure.com/

> **If you want to check the configuration use below script:**

**script :**

`SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX(db_name(),'edition') AS ServiceTier , DATABASEPROPERTYEX(db_name(),'serviceobjective') AS ComputeSize`

[image]

Comment: You are scaling a SQL DB or elastic pool? SQL DB I have no problem with the scalings, its elastic pool. ADF already has a contributor role in SQLServer. If you notice our errors are also different...."does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Sql/locations/elasticPoolOperationResults/read'"

Comment: Hi @DC07, If the scaling operation is working even though the activity fails, there may be a delay in the response from the API, which causes the activity to time out and fail. In that case, you can try increasing the timeout value in the web activity's settings to give the API more time to respond.

Comment: Additionally, you can check the azure portal activity logs to get more information about the failed activity and identify the root cause of the issue.